# Is using the stream of water from your kitchen faucet wasteful?

Tags: kitchens, sink

Am I wasting water and/money if I choose to wash a dish with the stream of water vs. the sprayer?

Comment: Depends on how you wash dishes. For example, he most efficient technique for larger quantities of dishes is one basin of soapy water and one of clear water for rinse, rather than running the water for each item.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a home improvement project.

Comment: The way to save water is to work efficiently.  Use the one that's not awkward to use.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my sprayer had a slower flow rate than my faucet, and the faucet rinsed a dish faster than the sprayer. Since I replaced the fixture, the sprayer flow rate seems to equal the faucet flow rate, and the sprayer rinses a dish faster. From this I suspect that the answer will be different in different kitchens, and maybe even at different times.

The only way to settle the argument for your particular kitchen is to conduct an experiment.

First, time the operations. Wash two identical loads, one with the stream and one with the sprayer. Use your kitchen timer or a water-resistant stopwatch to time both operations. Repeat the comparison several times for consistency.

Now, stopper the sink and run the stream for the amount of time taken to wash a load with the stream. Measure the depth of water in the sink. Drain the sink and repeat the measurement with the sprayer and the sprayer wash time. Compare the depth measurements.

I think you will discover that the amount of water you will save over the lifetime of the sink fixtures, using the more water-efficient method, will be significantly less than the amount of water you wasted performing the experiments.

But at least you know who won the argument.